# Ignoring a subfolder with .htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In my public_html I have 2 Folders, wordpress and tickets. I currently have the `/wordpress` directory working via mod_rewrite so that the URL's look nice. I'd like to setup an instance of `OSTicket`, and upon navigating to example.com/tickets to start the configuration, I'm hit with a Wordpress `404 error`.

My root `.htaccess` looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/tickets/.*
RewriteRule ^tickets - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /wordpress/index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I also have a `.htaccess` in the tickets folder, with;

```
RewriteEngine off
```

If anyone has some insight or perhaps something I should look into it would be most appreciated, thankyou all kindly.

Comment: Comment out `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/tickets/.*` line.

Comment: Doing that gives me a HTTP 500 error now, running the stock /tickets/setup/install.php gives that error, though If I create just a test.php in the setup dir, it will actually show the content of the page, which is very weird. Thanks for your help anubhava

Comment: You will need to check Apache error.log and see why is 500 coming.

Comment: Alright I'l check on that and report back, thanks a lot.

Comment: Is /tickets another WordPress install? If so, that directory needs its own htaccess file to run unique links.

Comment: Thanks Nathanial; its not another wordpress install, its an OSTicket install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The condition you have is the opposite of your match. They can't both be right. Drop the condition permanently, and amend the rule to this:

   ```
   RewriteRule ^tickets(?:$|/) - [L]
   ```

   That ensures `/tickets-foo/` still goes to WordPress and that you're not matching case-insensitively when your filesystem is case-sensitive.
2. Temporarily rename the tickets dir. Create another one with only an index document in it, content is irrelevant but put *something* in. Visit `example.com/tickets` and you should see your aforementioned content.

I'm betting the issue is not in the `.htaccess` nor WordPress.

Comment: Thanks Walf; I've added your suggestions and I was able to view the newly created index file, I think something more is going on here so I'll dig into the apache logs and figure it out, thanks!

Comment: If the URL in your browser is changing when you get the 500, then the network panel of your debugger may be helpful, too. Ensure you're using `RewriteBase /tickets/` in that subdirectory's `.htaccess` if there are any rewrites there.